# DNN HTML Module on 9.1.1 throwing the following error

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Since applying the latest critical security update, all pages that have the HTML module on them are throwing the following error resulting in a 404 page for the user.  Please advise!  Is there a good replacement module that we can use instead?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'ModuleContext' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 41:             {
Line 42:                 var wasReplacing = false;
Line 43:                 ModuleContext.Settings["MyTokensReplace"] = false;
Line 44:                 if (ModuleContext.Settings["TEXTHTML_ReplaceTokens"] != "") {
Line 45:                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(ModuleContext.Settings["TEXTHTML_ReplaceTokens"]) == true) {
```

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be related to the MyTokens module.  See the post on their website here:

https://www.dnnsharp.com/helpcenter/case/62435